# Calculate how many numbers were summed from 1 to n

Tags: python, math

I have a math question.
Having a sum of number from 1 to n. For example it may be:

```
sum([i for i in range(46)])
```

So the sum of it equals 1035.
Now my question is, knowing just sum - 1035 and that we start from 1. I want to calculate n.
How can I do that

Comment: Hint: Sum(1 to n) = n*(n+1)/2

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first n integers is `n*(n+1)/2`

So using the quadratic formula (and skipping the possibility of no real roots)

```py
import math

s = 1035
n = (-1 + math.sqrt(1 + 8*s))/2 # the other root is negative
print(n)
45.0
```

which in python3 division is a float.

Note too -- although you probably knew this -- that `range(46)` sums 1 + 2 + .... + 45. The upper end of `range` is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

The formula to calculate sum of upto `n` numbers is `n*(n+1)/2`.

checkout https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/

Comment: Yea but I'm not looking for sum, I want to know n. Sum is already known to me, I want to check n.

Comment: `sum = n*(n+1)/2` you could substitute sum and calculate for n.

Answer (score 0):

The summation will actually start from 0 and it will go to 45. You can test this by printing out the values:

```
for i in range(46):
    print(i)
```

To reverse the summation you will want to use the formula for sum of first n numbers, n*(n+1)/2 and equate this to the sum, 1035.

solving the equation you will get the quadratic n^2 + n - 2070 = 0

now you will need to get the roots. Only the positive root will matter in this case, we will use the quadratic formula to get the roots:

D = 1^2 - 4*1*(-2070);

x = (-1 + sqrt(D) / 2)

```
(math.sqrt(sum(i for i in range(46))*8 + 1) - 1) / 2
```

this will give you the last value that was added, 45. Now you can just add 1 to this to get 46.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
import math
def find_n_sum(s):
    d=1+8*s
    if (-1+math.sqrt(d))%2 == 0:
        return (-1+math.sqrt(d))/2
    else:
        return "Text to return if it doesn't exist"
```